# replacing quotes, commas, apostrophes w/ regex - python/pandas

Tags: python, string, pandas, replace, dataframe

I have a column with addresses, and sometimes it has these characters I want to remove => `'` - `"` - `,`(apostrophe, double quotes, commas)

I would like to replace these characters with space in one shot.  I'm using pandas and this is the code I have so far to replace one of them.

```
test['Address 1'].map(lambda x: x.replace(',', ''))
```

Is there a way to modify these code so I can replace these characters in one shot?  Sorry for being a noob, but I would like to learn more about pandas and regex.

Your help will be appreciated!

Comment: try this: `test['Address 1'].str.replace(r'[\'\",]*', '')`

Comment: i'm not familiar w/ `lambda`, what's its purpose? is it because of the map method?  Also, it looks like I didn't need the map method, just straight `str.replace`, when do you use map?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can use [`str.replace`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.replace.html):

```
test['Address 1'] = test['Address 1'].str.replace(r"[\"\',]", '')
```

Sample:

```
import pandas as pd

test = pd.DataFrame({'Address 1': ["'aaa",'sa,ss"']})
print (test)
  Address 1
0      'aaa
1    sa,ss"

test['Address 1'] = test['Address 1'].str.replace(r"[\"\',]", '')
print (test)
  Address 1
0       aaa
1      sass
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's the pandas solution:
To apply it to an entire dataframe use, [df.replace](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html#pandas.DataFrame.replace). Don't forget the \ character for the apostrophe.
Example:

```
import pandas as pd
df = #some dataframe
df.replace('\'','', regex=True, inplace=True)
```

Comment: hey, i'm wondering why the backslash is needed here, i've googled a bit but can't find a good explanation, do you have a link or anything similar?

Comment: The reason you need a ''\" is because you can't use certain characters in a command like: \, ', or " , so you have to use a "\" before those characters