# could not convert string to float: ' 8,400,000,000

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, machine-learning

im new to machine learning and i stuck with this error that says:

```
could not convert string to float: ' 8,400,000,000
```

what should i do?

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeRegressor
from sklearn.metrics import mean_absolute_error
from sklearn import linear_model


df = pd.read_csv("housePrice.csv")

print(df.isna().sum())
print(df.head())
print(df.describe())

x = df[["Area","Room","Parking","Warehouse"]]
np.reshape(x , (3479, 4))
y = df.Price

print(x.shape)
print(y.shape)

print(df.info())

filler = df.fillna(method="ffill")
filler = df.fillna(method="bfill")



train_x, test_x, train_y, test_y = train_test_split(x , y ,random_state=0, test_size=0.3)
dt = DecisionTreeRegressor()


dt.fit(train_x , train_y)

pred_y = dt.predict(test_x)
print("MAE:" ,mean_absolute_error(test_y , pred_y))
```

Comment: There exsit least 1 column that is `str` rather than numerical `dtype`, convert it by `df['COLUMN_NAME'] = df['COLUMN_NAME'].astype(float)`

Answer (score 2):

According to the error message: `could not convert string to float: ' 8,400,000,000'`, one of the columns in your data frame has a value `' 8,400,000,000` which is throwing the error as all data that goes into a DecisionTree needs to be numeric. All the `str` type data need to be converted to numeric first.

For the specific value in this error message, `' 8,400,000,000` the commas `,` , the preceding space and the apostrophe need to be removed in order to make it a numeric format that can be converted to a `float` type.

One way to do that would be:

```
df[COLUMN1] = df[COLUMN1].replace("'", '') # Replace apostrophe with empty string
df[COLUMN1] = df[COLUMN1].replace(",", '') # Relace comma with empty string
df[COLUMN1] = df[COLUMN1].replace(" ", '') # Replace whitespace with empty string
df[COLUMN1] = df[COLUMN1].astype(float) # Finally, convert column to float type
```

Here's another SO entry that looks at replacing these characters in a pandas column: [replacing quotes, commas, apostrophes w/ regex - python/pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39214938/4091956)